# How this document is able to detect a cookie when it didn't set at all?

Tags: javascript, cookies

This is one script that sets the cookie with *some* html file.

```
window.onload=init;

function init() {
var userName="";
if(document.cookie != "") {
    username=document.cookie.split("=")[1];
    document.getElementById("name_field").value = username;
}

document.getElementById("name_field").onblur = setCookie;
}

function setCookie() {
var exprDate = new Date();
exprDate.setMonth(exprDate.getMonth() + 6);

var username = document.getElementById("name_field").value;
document.cookie = "username=" + username + ";path=/;expires=" + exprDate.toGMTString();
}
```

This is another script with some *different* html file, (that had not saved a cookie in the past) that checks if there is a cookie saved with this document.

```
window.onload = initTest;

function initTest() {
if(document.cookie == "") alert("No,cookies stored !");
else alert("cookies found !");
}
```

To my surprise the result when i run the 2nd html file with the second script,is **cookies found** Why is that ? When that document has not saved a cookie then how come `document.cookie != ""` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies are set per domain and/or path.

Examples:

- `http://www.example.com/foo.html` **Cookie:** `x=x; max-age=3600;` is visible at `http://www.example.com/*`, but not at `http://other.example.com/`
- `http://www.example.com/foo.html` **Cookie:** `x=x; max-age=3600; domain=.example.com` is visible at `http://*.example.com/*` and `http://example.com/*`
- https protocols-only: **Cookie:** `x=x; max-age=3600; secure`
- The path can be changed to the current path, or any parent directory. The default path is the current directory. E.g.: `x=x; max-age=3600; path=/`

Comment: @ Suhail Gupta - what Rob W is saying is that *some* html file can set cookies that are availble to any *different* html file as long as it is under same domain and cookie (when setting it) wasn't restricted to some path that is different to *different* html file.